# Spring Boot: How to handle 400 error caused by @RequestParam?

Tags: spring-boot

```
public String(@RequestParam Integer id) {
// ...
}
```

If `id` parameter cannot be found in the current request, I will get 400 status code with empty response body. Now I want to return JSON string for this error, how can I make it?

PS: I don't want to use `@RequestParam(required = false)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made it.
Just override `handleMissingServletRequestParameter()` method in your own `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` class.

```
@Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMissingServletRequestParameter(MissingServletRequestParameterException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        log.warn("miss Request Param");

        return new ResponseEntity<>(new FoxResponse(ErrorCode.ARG_INVALID), status);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use `@PathVariable`, hope it will meets your requirement.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<User> getUser(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
    System.out.println("Fetching User with id " + id);
    User user = userService.findById(id);
    if (user == null) {
        System.out.println("User with id " + id + " not found");
        return new ResponseEntity<User>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<User>(user, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same problem, but exception thrown is `MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException`. With `@ControllerAdvice` error handler all data about `@RequestParam` error can be retrieved. Here is complete class that worked for me

```
@ControllerAdvice
@RequestMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class ControllerExceptionHandler {

  @ExceptionHandler(value = {MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException.class})
  @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
  @ResponseBody
  public Map<String, String> handleServiceCallException(MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException e) {
    Map<String, String> errMessages = new HashMap<>();
    errMessages.put("error", "MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException");
    errMessages.put("message", e.getMessage());
    errMessages.put("parameter", e.getName());
    errMessages.put("errorCode", e.getErrorCode());
    return errMessages;
  }

}
```